# Making product cards for each item in the database

Tags: php, html, web-deployment-project

I am currently working on a schoolproject where I have to make a storepage for a liquor store. For this we have a database with the products the store sells. I want to make the products appear on the page on cards, much like you see in other webstores. however I ran into a problem which I cannot fix.

When there was just 1 product in the store it formed a nice card as it was supposed to do, but when I added a second item to the database it placed the card into the existing one instead of next to it. I have included the code and a screenshot of the current page. If you need more then I will happily supply you the needed info.

```
<?php include "pdo.php" ?>

<?php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM product';
$products = $pdo -> prepare($sql);
$products -> execute();
$producten = $products ->fetchAll(); ?>


<!-- Include header.php. Bevat: header, body tag & donkere navigatiebalk  -->
<?php  include 'header.php' ?>

<div class="container tc-white">
<?php 

// if statement om te kijken of er waarden zijn in de array producten
if($producten != NULL){



// Array keys omzetten in variabelen.
    foreach($producten as $product)
    $id = $product["productID"];
    $name = $product["naam"];
    $land = $product["land"];
    $inventory = $product["voorraad"];
    $price = $product["prijs"];
    $brand = $product["producent"];
}

// Als er geen waarden in de array zijn gevonden:
else{
    echo "<h3> Geen producten gevonden </3>";
}
?>


<?php
foreach($producten as $cardloop)
echo 
'<div class="col-md-4 mt-4 mt-sm-0 card-container">
 <div class="card text-center product p-4 pt-5 border-0 h-100 rounded-0">
  [product-image]
  <div class="card-body p-4 py-0 h-xs-440p">' .
  $name .  " " . $price;
     ?>
   
  </div>
  <p class="btn w-100 px-4 text-center mx-auto">
   [button]
 </div>
</div>

</div>

<!-- Include footer.php. bevat: body sluit tag -->
<?php include 'footer.php' ?>
```

[image: Store page]

Hopefully you can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are generating bad HTML structure. If you take a look at the source of your page (right click > `View page source`), you'll see more opened divs than closed ones. This is because when you don't put curly braces around your `foreach` content, only the *next command* will be considered part of it. So you will echo the opening div tags *n* times, but close them only *once*.

Comment: Also, I'd advise you to choose one syntax - don't mix echoing HTML with opening/closing the PHP tag to output HTML. Pick one and stick to it, consistency is important.

Answer (score 0):

you have to properly open and close both foreach

```
<?php include "pdo.php" ?>

<?php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM product';
$products = $pdo -> prepare($sql);
$products -> execute();
$producten = $products ->fetchAll(); ?>


<!-- Include header.php. Bevat: header, body tag & donkere navigatiebalk  -->
<?php  include 'header.php' ?>

<div class="container tc-white">
<?php 

// if statement om te kijken of er waarden zijn in de array producten
if($producten != NULL){



// Array keys omzetten in variabelen.
    foreach($producten as $product)
    {
    $id = $product["productID"];
    $name = $product["naam"];
    $land = $product["land"];
    $inventory = $product["voorraad"];
    $price = $product["prijs"];
    $brand = $product["producent"];
  }  // added braces at the begin and end of foreach
}

// Als er geen waarden in de array zijn gevonden:
else{
    echo "<h3> Geen producten gevonden </3>";
}
?>


<?php
foreach($producten as $cardloop)
{  // added braces at the begin and end of foreach
echo 
'<div class="col-md-4 mt-4 mt-sm-0 card-container">
 <div class="card text-center product p-4 pt-5 border-0 h-100 rounded-0">
  [product-image]
  <div class="card-body p-4 py-0 h-xs-440p">' .
  $name .  " " . $price;
     ?>
   
  </div>
  <p class="btn w-100 px-4 text-center mx-auto">
   [button]
 </div>
</div>
<?php } ?> 

</div>

<!-- Include footer.php. bevat: body sluit tag -->
<?php include 'footer.php' ?>
```

Comment: Right I see. Now I indeed have 2 cards. The only thing is that it makes 2 cards of the last product in the database instead of one of both

Comment: @JulianBerendsen: Did you get the answer for your question, or there is a second part to your question. if that is not in the question, please update question with the relevant details along with the screenshot of the current page or a demo